# PHP Constant Question

Tags: php, directory, constants

What is the

```
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
```

constant contain?

I can't find anything on google explaining this but its used in my OOP book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either '/' or '\' depending on your OS. Use it when specifying paths to make code more portable between Unix-y systems and Windows.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I guessed it was but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

It is the separator that link folder in a path like "/" in :

here/is/my/path

The separator depends on which OS you are running your website.

On windows, this is "\" :

my\path\to\folder

On Unix it's "/"

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of on the tin.

When I run

```
var_dump(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

I get (on my Linux/Ubuntu box)

```
string(1) "/"
```

(A forward slash). This is the separator string that applies to file paths on the OS your server is running on. It will most probably be a `\` (backslash) on Windows systems.